# Google apk installer

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Did anyone know how does google installs applications without keeping apk file into your mobile phone?
I'm trying to create a new appshop and i think that "downloading apk file" directly without having the permission to delete it after that, is now the solution.

Thanks !

Comment: I suppose it downloads the apk and delete it after the installation. If not deleted the apk files are accessible to rooted devices, and will take a lot of space, for example: installing a 30Mb app from GPS will take approximately 30Mb, while installing the same app from your store would take about 60Mb.

Comment: Thank you, but how can you test if the app is installed ?
Another thing, is that google downloads the app into your phone and installs it automatically.
If it's not installed it will delete it as well ...

Comment: You can check programmatically if a certain package is installed. Knowing this i think the process is something like: download apk, install (you already accepted to give the necessary permissions), check if package is installed (if not give message error), delete apk. But keep in mind this is just what I think play store dose.

Comment: I totally agree.

Thank you Ayoub :)